# Is there a way to determine the duration of an audio file

Tags: android

In android, what is the simplest way to determine the duration of an audio file (assume I have an URI of the file on the phone)?

Do I need to create and prepare an media player for each file I want to determine the duration of the file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MediaScanner is running on the phone then you can use MediaStore to get that information.

[MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html)