# How to tell if a sound is still playing in soundpool

Tags: android, soundpool

I wish to play series of sounds using soundpool, but want to wait till each sound has completed before starting the next one. I can not find any `.isPlaying()` type function. Is there one?

Comment: is there a .getLength() method?

Comment: soundPool.getLength() does not exist.

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709883/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-an-audio-file-duration-in-android ? as the author said, rather heavy.