# Detect if sound is playing/managing toggle button

Tags: android, adt, soundpool

I am having trouble figuring out how to manage a togglebutton that turns music on/off. When a user clicks it on, it should just loop continuously until it is turned off. I am using soundpool, if there was someway i could detect if my media was playing either by using soundpool or media player that would help. But i cant find anything relevant in documentation and similar question doesnt have a good answer; [How to tell if a sound is still playing in soundpool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832278/how-to-tell-if-a-sound-is-still-playing-in-soundpool?lq=1)

I have this so far:

```
final ToggleButton tglbuttn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        final SoundPool mySp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        final int soundId = mySp.load(this, R.raw.music, 1);

        tglbuttn.setChecked(????????); //what could go here?
        tglbuttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
```

If i could somehow get something like this bluetooth toggleswitch going, but with soundpool/mediaplayer, a way to tie in the actual status of media playing with the state of the togglebutton:

```
tglbtn.setChecked(myBluetooth.isEnabled());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [isChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29) method to toggle the button. Try this:

```
//Make your activity implements OnClickListener
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Then:

```
//In your OnCreate()
tglbuttn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Finally:

```
//Add this method to your Activity
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==tglbuttn) {
        if(v.isChecked())
            play();
        else                
            stop();
        tglbuttn.setChecked(!tglbuttn.isChecked()); //It will be toggled
     }
}
```

Comment: I get that isChecked() is not defined for View, if i add a cast, the app crashes once the button is pressed. With a not valid cast ouput in LogCat.

Comment: It is because tglbuttn is not defined in the inner class. Try the edit.

Comment: Void is an unvalid type for the variable onClick, when removed onClick cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Make sure you implement `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Had it implemented, still had multiple errors though. I was having playback issues as well, i didnt realize how small the files need to be for soundpool to work properly, so mediaplayer is actually more appropriate for my needs anyways, and there is a isPlaying() method as well, which is what i needed originally.