# Android - How to make the phone vibrate to the music playing

Tags: android, audio-player, android-vibration, android-music-player

I am new to Android development. I want to make an app that is essentially a music player but the phone can vibrate to the beat of the music playing. I remember the earliest Nokia phones had this feature, I want to recreate this for fun.

My question: is this possible as an Android app? If so, what are the general approaches? 
Do I have to analyse the sound patterns of the song then alter the vibration intensity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I got interested with this question and after deep research I figured out how to do that. So here we go.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Vibrator;

private Vibrator vibrator;
private MediaPlayer player;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    player.start();

    //HERE WE WILL START VIBRATION

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    player.stop();
    vibrator.cancel();
}
```

This is general approach for playing music and now work tight with the method `vibrate();`.
From all of constructors of class [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) we need this one:

```
public void vibrate (long milliseconds, AudioAttributes attributes);
```

It was added in `API 21`
As first parameter we can pass the duration of the song and this duration we can get this way ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709883/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-an-audio-file-duration-in-android)):

```
String mediaPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://<your-package-name>/raw/filename").getPath();
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mediaPath);
String duration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
```

As second parameter we need to create [AudioAttributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html) with the help of [AudioAttributes.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.Builder.html):

```
vibrator.vibrate(duration, new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build());
```

Please, **NOTE**: I haven't tried it. But the doc said it should works fine.
Let me know if that is completed way.
Best regards.

P.S. Don't forget permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```